# how to make users to manage their facebook pages in my website for adding some custom landing tabs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, fan-page

how to make users to manage their facebook pages in my website for adding some custom landing tabs which i created in my webpage.when are user clicks on that custom tab, it should generate a dialog box or facebook API , with the list of pages which the current user has created and he should be able to select either of one page and that page should redirect him to that selected page in facebook with that custom tab.. Please developers help out me with some coding. 
for example:follow this site  hyly...

i was stucked up with this problem from last 1 month..hope you will make me to overcome this problem...

Answer (score 0):

1. To retrieve the current pages a user administer you need the [`manage_pages`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) permission and then to query: `/me/accounts`
2. Then you can install an app into a [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs) by issuing a HTTP POST to `PAGE_ID/tabs` ([example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/524/))
3. No one will build (code) an app for you. This community is about solving technical issues, i.e. you have done *all* the work and stuck in some points which you need help with.

Comment: thanq..everything has went well upto now , but am unable to retrieve all the fan pages of current user..

Comment: if you have granted the `manage_pages` account, `/me/accounts` *should* return all the pages. Are you sure that the user is actually an admin of the missing pages? if yes, I would report a bug.

Comment: sorry i couldn't get the clear path in declaration, can u give some lines of code with an example...For my better understanding..